# Regular expression in angular gives unmatched parenthesis error

Tags: regex, angularjs

I am trying to validate email in angular using regular expression pattern from http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html as follows:

```
input.form-control(type="email", placeholder="Email", name="email", ng-model='doctor.email', ng-pattern='[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?')
```

which gives this error:

```
    Error: /home/pravin/zyoba/nimbus/nimbus-web/views/addDoc.jade:50
        48|               .form-group.clearfix
        49|                 .col-xs-7
      > 50|                   input.form-control(type="email", placeholder="Email", name="email", ng-model='doctor.email', ng-pattern='[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?')
        51|                 span.font-red.font-23 * 
        52|                 span.icon-form-cross(ng-show="docRegForm.email.$dirty &&  validation.test(docRegForm.email.$error)")
        53| 

    start character ( does not match end character ]
        at Object.Lexer.bracketExpression (/home/pravin/zyoba/nimbus/nimbus-web/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:130:46)
        at Object.Lexer.attrs (/home/pravin/zyoba/nimbus/nimbus-web/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:581:24)
        at Object.Lexer.next (/home/pravin/zyoba/nimbus/nimbus-web/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:867:15)
        at Object.Lexer.lookahead (/home/pravin/zyoba/nimbus/nimbus-web/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:113:46)
        at Parser.lookahead (/home/pravin/zyoba/nimbus/nimbus-web/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:100:23)
        at Parser.peek (/home/pravin/zyoba/nimbus/nimbus-web/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:77:17)
        at Parser.tag (/home/pravin/zyoba/nimbus/nimbus-web/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:733:22)
        at Parser.parseTag (/home/pravin/zyoba/nimbus/nimbus-web/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:719:17)
        at Parser.parseExpr (/home/pravin/zyoba/nimbus/nimbus-web/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:188:21)
        at Parser.block (/home/pravin/zyoba/nimbus/nimbus-web/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:689:25)
```

I am a regular expression noob, and dont know complex regular expressions. Please somebody help me debug the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely that you have a single quote (`'`) inside the regex, as well as to delimit the start and end of the regex string.

You will need to escape the inner quote somehow.

Comment: turns out problem was the single quote. I used double quote to wrap the regular expression. Now it works.

Comment: @Pravin Good to hear. Don't forget to accept the best answer that helped you solve the problem, and upvote any helpful ones. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

In your regular expression, you are using the single quote character which is also used as the quote character for the expression.  You need to escape it.  Try the following:

```
ng-pattern='[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?')
```

Comment: thanks mate... the problem was the single quote. I used the double quote to wrap the regular expression. Now it works perfectly.